# Apart from the GoF patterns, where can I find info/a collection of other patterns that I commonly see

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, computer-science, clean-architecture

I'm asking this as I'm early in my career and I want to see if I could find some good resources to learn more so I can understand some of the design patterns (that I will mention to you) and how to implement them. Here are the details:

I'm familiar with the GoF design patterns and their categorization under Creational, Behavioral, and Structural. However, while working on different projects I have seen different patterns being implemented to separate concerns of the various classes in a codebase.

I will name-drop some patterns that I have seen/worked with off the top of my head. The list is:

- Models
- Views
- Controllers
- Presenters
- ViewModels (All the above come from MVC, MVP, MVVM)
- Resources (Appears to be similar to controllers)
- Services
- DTOs
- DAOs
- DALs
- Repositories
- Entities (I think all of these have to do with Domain-Driven Design)

A quick example of where I have seen these is in recommended framework for Android which is MVVM but also includes the Repository pattern

[Recommended Android Design Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aH8l.png)

So my question is, all of the aforementioned patterns, where can I find comprehensive resources/collections that discuss design patterns (including the aforementioned, as well as others), when to use what, etc.

I apologize, I am quite lacking in knowledge in this topic, therefore, I am likely grouping many unrelated things together, if someone could please explain how these patterns divided up, that would be much appreciated.

I tried finding some resources that had collections of these design patterns, but I'm not sure that I have found anything fruitful, so I am reaching out to the community.

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a lot of design patterns implemented [here](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns)

Comment: Thanks! That should be a good resource.